# Mahaney's theorem and converting SAT to equivalent language

Tags: complexity-theory, computability

Language $L$ is sparse if there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $|L ∩ \{0,1\}^n| ≤ p(n)$. Thus, if there are at most polynomial number of strings for each length $n$ in the set $S$ (where $S$ represents the language $L$), the set $S$ is a sparse set.

Mahaney's theorem states that if an NP-complete language is Karp-reducible to a sparse language then P=NP.

As I understand, the $S$ would consist strings of form $\langle Q_i, x_i\rangle$ where $Q_i$ is a 3SAT instance, and $x_i$ is one of its variables. Thus, for all $k$ inputs accepted by any $Q_i$, we would have $k$ strings of the form above (one for each accepted input $x_i$). And the length would be the size of the resultant string for $\langle Q_i, x_i \rangle$.

If my understanding is correct, can someone help with a small example how to  convert a SAT problem into equivalent string. The inputs $x_i$'s would be in binary already, but not clear how to get the string equivalent to $\langle Q_i, x_i\rangle$?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. We don't think that SAT is Karp-reducible to a sparse language, and in particular we don't know how such a hypothetical sparse language would look like.

Comment: Of course other wise P=NP :). I meant an example of converting a single instance of SAT to a equivalent language in binary set S.I know reductions b/w NPC Problems, but not sure how to convert SAT into an equivalent language.

Comment: It seems you are referring to a particular proof of Mahaney's theorem. Your question doesn't make too much sense outside of this context. Perhaps you could add a link to the particular proof, and which step exactly you are having troubles with.

Comment: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~jkatz/complexity/f05/lecture6.pdf I am using these notes. The question was in 2 parts. (1)  If my generic understanding of the Mahaney's Theorem is correct in general. The notes use a language LSAT and they mention if LSAT is Karp reducible to Sparse Language P=NP. (2) How to convert a concrete instance of a SAT problem to a language problem (a reduction or encoding process). I am not clear regarding this.

Comment: I still can't understand your second question. A Karp reduction from a language $L_1$ to a language $L_2$ is a polytime function $f$ such that $x \in L_1$ iff $f(x) \in L_2$. Is this the sense in which you mean "convert a concrete instance of a SAT problem to a language problem"? If so, what are $L_1,L_2$?

Comment: For example let $L_1$ be a simplest of language containing a single 3SAT instance with 3 clauses: (1) ~a+b+c=1 (2)  a+~c+~d=1 (3) ~b+c+d=1. We need to convert this into a set S of binary strings equivalent to $\langle Q_i, x_i \rangle$ that represent this language. How to do that?

Comment: Unfortunately I think you don't understand the concepts of language, instance and reduction well enough. I suggest contacting a TA.

Comment: I understand the concept of reductions prof. (3SAT, vertex cover, Clique etc.) but all the reductions I have seen, the mapping is One-to-One in terms of solutions (eg: b/w SAT instance and reduced NAESAT instance). Similarly, the mapping b/w problem instance is also One-to-One, i.e. I have not seen two 3SAT instances map to a single NAESAT instance. So, I am struggling to see if problem instances and each of their solutions have a one to one mapping, then how it the potential of any dense NPComplete problem reducing to a sparse language remains open.

Comment: Unless the question if any of the NPComplete problems is dense is still open. Or there is a many to one mapping in reductions (I haven't seen an example of that). I am doing an independent study as I graduated from univ. some time back (we didn't have much theory). So I use the forum as a guide if I get stuck.